# Data getting repeated when fetched from the database while trying to display in bootstrap modals in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and was trying to display data after fetching  from the database.
This is my template code:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<div class="card w-75">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h3 class="card-title"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" style="color: green">{{obj.Name }}<br></h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Show Policy</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I got the correct response till here and was getting different data as in different content of the data but after this all the code is showing the first data (the same content) only.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">

               <h1>{{ obj.Name }}</h1><br>


        </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

       <h3>Department</h3><br>
        {{ obj.Department }}<br>
        <h3>Policy</h3>
       {{ obj.Policy }}<br>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

my models.py code is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

# Create your models here.
class Gov(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Department = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    Policy= models.CharField(max_length = 500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the following view that gives you the object for your template:

```
def some_view(request, person_id):
    obj = Person.objects.get(id=person_id)
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'obj': obj})
```

And let's say the model for that is like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(......)
    ....
```

If this is how it is, then the object you're passing from this view should look like `{{ obj.name }}`. Don't capitalize it.

If you changed the object's dictionary key to `'person'`, but kept the value as the variable `obj`, then you would add it to the template like `{{ person.name }}`.